# How to cast integer to byte in Python but with as same behavior in Java?

Tags: java, python, casting, byte

In Java for example:

```
int i = 171;
(byte) i; // will return -85
```

Is there a way to replicate this behavior in Python? I've already tried a bunch of things but I can't seem to replicate how it works in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is how it's done:

```
int.from_bytes(bytes([171]), byteorder='big', signed=True)
```